# Why using a framework to make Http requests in Android instead of using its own classes to make this?

Tags: android, httprequest, rest-client

There are many frameworks to make http requests in Android, like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) and [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/). But also, Android has its own classes to make this type of request, like [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and [HttpClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

So what is the advantage of using some framework like these mentioned?

My doubt is if there is some big advantage in make requests using some framework, instead of using Android native classes.

Comment: Additional functionality and abstractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage is things like retries, restarts, threading & synchronization, and state management will be handled for you.  This comes at the expense of configurability, but it's not a huge expense.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider the right answer. But still learning things like these.